# Python client to access CalDAV via OAuth2 on Nextcloud

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, caldav, nextcloud

The canonical [examples](https://github.com/python-caldav/caldav/blob/master/examples/basic_usage_examples.py) for using CalDAV always use username/password authentication. However Nextcloud supports OAuth2, therefore I would like to use CalDAV via oauth.

I already have done the same with the Google calendar API, but just adapting the `oauth2client` sample provided by Google:

```
client_secrets = 'client_secrets.json'
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(client_secrets, scope="",
                                      message=tools.message_if_missing(client_secrets))
storage = file.Storage('calendar_credentials.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage)

http = credentials.authorize(http=build_http())
```

by replacing `build_http()` by an instance of `caldav.DAVClient` does not work. The internal `request()` APIs are quite different and calling any method of the caldav client will miserably fail when wrapped by `authorize()`. So, the question is: how to integrate `caldav.DAVClient` with `oauth2client`?

Also documentation on using OAuth with nextCloud is scarce. I have found [this posting](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/nc12-build-in-oauth2-client-authentification/14852/2), but it is still not obvious what goes where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the configuration. In Nextcloud, go to the security settings (https://mycloud.example.com/settings/admin/security). There is a section `OAuth 2.0 clients`. Add a client. You can use any name, e.g. `calendar`, but it is important that the redirect URI is `http://localhost:8080`. Why? `tools.run_flow()` will instantiate an http server to receive the authentication call on this address by default. Click "add". You should now see a new client ID. Copy the client ID and the secret (click the eye icon to reveal) to [client_secrets.json](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets) which should then look like this:

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "stuff copied from Client Identifier",
    "client_secret": "stuff copied from secret",
    "auth_uri": "https://mycloud.example.com/index.php/apps/oauth2/authorize",
    "token_uri": "https://mycloud.example.com/index.php/apps/oauth2/api/v1/token",
    "redirect_uris": []
  }
}
```

When you now run the example from the question section, your browser should automatically be directed to the mycloud.example.com instance and there should be a message saying "You are about to grant **calendar** access to your mycloud.example.com account." Click "Grant access". After entering your username and password, the browser should now be redirected to http://localhost:8080 and you should see the message "The authentication flow has completed."

Notes:

- I found no difference whether `client_secrets.json` starts with `web`
  or with `installed`. It must be one of these two, however.
- apparently, `redirect_uris` can remain empty.

Now the programming question (this is a programmer's forum after all...)

The constructor of `caldav.DAVClient` allows for an `auth` parameter, which should be an instance of `requests.auth.AuthBase`. So let's create one:

```
from requests.auth import AuthBase


class OAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, credentials):
        self.credentials = credentials

    def __call__(self, r):
        self.credentials.apply(r.headers)
        return r
```

Now instead of calling `credentials.authorize(http=build_http())` as in the original example from Google, we write

```
caldav_client = caldav.DAVClient(
    "https://mycloud.example.com/remote.php/dav/",
    auth=OAuth(credentials))
```

That's it! We can now write

```
principal = caldav_client.principal()
calendars = principal.calendars()
```

as in the [original example](https://github.com/python-caldav/caldav/blob/master/examples/basic_usage_examples.py).

Comment: thank u for the example. May I know is there anyway we can build that oauth process on server side without using going through the process of authenticating on the front end?